# Cross-referencing Chapter numbers or names by rmarkdown

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, cross-reference

In trying to find a way in Rmarkdown for cross-referencing chapters which were auto-numbering and/or by its named to do something like

```
"As I explained hundred pages ago in \ref{ch:Chapter_Label}....."
```

and then the generated pdf document produced has something like:

```
"As I explained hundred pages ago in Chapter 3....."
```

or

```
"As I explained hundred pages ago in <Chapter Name> ....."
```

I was thinking in some mechanism like:

```
\chapter{My_Title} \label{ch:1}
```

And then everywhere inside the text I use `\ref{ch:1}` I would get either the "My_Title" or the "Chapter 1" (or whatever auto-numbering it got) embedded by the text.

Seemed the hyperref package is not working by Rmarkdown or I'm missing something.

Does anybody can help me?

Comment: [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides `\nameref` and/or `\autoref`, which seems to be what you're after.

Comment: @Werner: for some reason that I don´t know yet, `hyerref` `\usepackage` is not working after labelling `\chapter{Chapter One}` with `\label{C1}`. Pdf is resulting with "??" marks for all the attempts used: `\nameref{C1}` or `\autoref{C1}` `\ref{C1}`

Comment: Typically references require two compilations (which accesses the `.aux` file during the second compilation). Perhaps Rmarkdown is failing to compile in this way?

Comment: @Werner Seems related with what you mentioned.....by opening and knit´ng by a new Rmarkdown, there was an output error pointing to `\usepackage{amsmath}´ which one after removed from preamble led to the pdf with the following result: "Here the cross-reference for _ChapterOne_  _chapter 1 1_". Seems I´m the right track...

Comment: [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) should not be a problem here...

Comment: Yihui (of rmarkdown, knitr) seems to working on a solution now ... -> https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/3

Comment: hi @maxheld..yes I have interacted with @Yihui when he was developing his package `bookdown` and tried (in advance) it for my case. However, I found other problems and I did not get the  pdf compilation by bookdown (pdf was not created) and even when compiling the tex directly from Texmaker , the syntax  `\@ref(label)` as well `\ref{section}` are resulting in `"??"` in the pdf. 
     Error: Failed to compile testebook.tex.

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been solved in [**bookdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) and documented in [Section 2.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html). Basically you use the syntax `\@ref(label)`, and `label` is your chapter identifier.